# Fast way to create virtual disks?

Tags: dd, disk, mkfs

I want to create virtual 500GB ext4 disks on external usb disks and samba/nfs shares.

For test purposes, I first tried with a 1GB file using the following commands.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/smbshare/VHD.img bs=1M count=1000
mkfs.ext4 /mnt/smbshare/VHD.img
```

It works to get a 1GB ext4 filesystem, but `dd` is slow (10MB/s). So I tried to create a 10GB file with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/smbshare/VHD2.img bs=1G seek=10 count=0`. It took few milliseconds, but in this case command `mkfs.ext4 /mnt/smbshare/VHD.img` returned the following error message:

> mke2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
>   warning: Unable to get device geometry for VHD2.img
>   VHD2.img: Permission denied while setting up superblock

Is there a fast way to create the file so it can be successfully formatted, for example by changing the `dd` parameters, adding a further step after `dd`, or by using an alternate way to create the file?

Comment: `Unable to get device geometry for VHD2.img` is just a warning. Can `permission denied` be because you created the file with `sudo` but then invoked `mkfs` without `sudo`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It finally appears that `sudo` solved the issue for the second `mkfs`, because the second `sudo dd` created a file `VHD2.img` with permissions `-rw-r--r--` while in the first case it created a file `VHD.img` with permissions `-rwxrw-rw-`. I wonder why different parameters of `dd` create files with different permissions ?